# GMail stopped working last night (CM 11)

Tags: cyanogenmod, gmail

I've been running CyanogenMod 11 (11-2014112-SNAPSHOT-M12-d2lte) on my Sprint Galaxy S3 since December.

Last night I saw a message flash on the screen saying something like "Android is updating", though I'm not exactly sure since it went away so quickly.

Shortly after that I got a message that Gmail has stopped working (Report, OK) and the icon on my home screen changed to the Android robot with the "com.google.andr" text below it.

My other GApps appear to be working fine.

How do I get GMail working again?

Comment: Wipe data/cache of your GMAIL app. If that didn't help wipe cache in recovery mode or reflash your ROM (no data wipe).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by uninstalling all updates, then updating the app from the app store. I first tried wiping cache and data like SuperThomasLab suggested but that didn't work.